cradle fabAnchorMode didn't work when I add fabAlignmentMode into center
I want to make this FAB in the center of BottomAppBar
Before center :

But when I add app:fabAlignmentMode="center", the FAB went to center and the effect of app:fabAnchorMode="cradle" were gone
After center :

How to solve this?
This is the XML code:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    ...

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabAnchorMode="cradle"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="0dp"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.Full"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I have tried to center the the FAB using app:layout_anchorGravity="center" without app:fabAlignmentMode="center" but still didn't work.
I'm using Material Design 3

You cannot directly use com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView as child of com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar, instead have a look at this SO question for a workaround.
